# web.xml error for Custom error page

Tags: spring, security

I am trying to create a custom error page to my project. I have the `errorController` and the `error.jsp` page. When I add the location error tag to the `web.xml` file, I get an error for 'invalid content was found starting with element location'. Is there any dependency I need to add to get rid of this error. Appreciate any replies. Thank you.

Comment: I added the error-code tag and the error went away, but that does not help me display the error page I created.

Comment: What servlet spec you are using? container 3.0+ or 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is your question without some code snippet.

But in general https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/basics6.htm is a good starting point to learn how to create a customized error page.